# get text from Excel data and click on web element Selenium radio button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, radio-button, apache-poi

Both tests work okay individually I need help merging them both.
I'm unable to test both together.
If sheet cell is read as a male it should click on the male radio button.
Please help me resolve this test
ExcelRead33.java will read the specific cell from excel sheet.
facebookradio.java will run a test on the radio button.
Excel file for data.

```
package testpoi;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;




public class facebookradio {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

WebElement male_radio_button=driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_a"));

male_radio_button.click();


WebElement female_radio_button=driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_9"));

female_radio_button.click();
```

ExcelRead33.java will read the specific cell from excel sheet.

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

    //How to read excel files using Apache POI
    public class ExcelRead33 {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/DDFREAD.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);

    //Read specific row and column 
    Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(8);
    //This will print data which I want to click 
    System.out.println(cell);
```

[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCW6G.jpg)

Comment: I think you mean "unable" not "unavailable."  Please show your attempt in the original post along with your code listing and what error you encountered when you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Sharpen your Core java skills ahead of learning Selenium.  This is a dirty code [without leveraging OOPs] of what you're trying to perform.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/october2018/Q52995381.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

    // Read specific row and column
    Row row = sheet.getRow(2);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(7);
    // This will print data which I want to click
    System.out.println(cell);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    if (cell.toString().contentEquals("male")) {
        WebElement male_radio_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='2']"));
        male_radio_button.click();
    } else {
        WebElement female_radio_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='1']"));
        female_radio_button.click();
    }
```